# visualize omics?

Tags: ros, knowrobtutorials, knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I was reading in commonsense knowledge here ' http://ias.in.tum.de/kb/wiki/index.php/Commonsense_reasoning_about_object_locations '
but I want to visualize parts of the output
so I run first `rosrun rosprolog rosprolog mod_vis` and open knowrob_omics from inside by `register_ros_package(knowrob_omics).` and then open visualization convas to start querying and visualizations of what geten out but it not success, so I want to know

---

that is all after launch mod_vis

```
?- register_ros_package(knowrob_omics).
% Parsed "locations.rdf" in 0.05 sec; 1,344 triples
Warning: /home/amal/ros/stacks/knowrob/knowrob_omics/prolog/omics.pl:137:
    Singleton variables: [O]
%  library(omics) compiled into omics 0.00 sec, 6,312 bytes
% /home/amal/ros/stacks/knowrob/knowrob_omics/prolog/init.pl compiled 0.06 sec, 65,300 bytes
true.

?- register_ros_package(ias_semantic_map).
% Parsed "comp_temporal.owl" in 0.01 sec; 164 triples
Warning: /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/comp_temporal/prolog/comp_temporal.pl:74:
    Goal (directive) failed: comp_temporal:owl_parser:owl_parse(../owl/comp_temporal.owl,false,false,true)
%    library(comp_temporal) compiled into comp_temporal 0.01 sec, 24,168 bytes
Warning: /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/comp_temporal/prolog/init.pl:30:
    Goal (directive) failed: user:owl_parser:owl_parse(/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/comp_temporal/owl/comp_temporal.owl,false,false,true)
%   /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/comp_temporal/prolog/init.pl compiled 0.02 sec, 27,548 bytes
% Parsed "comp_spatial.owl" in 0.00 sec; 52 triples
Warning: /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/comp_spatial/prolog/comp_spatial.pl:51:
    Goal (directive) failed: comp_spatial:owl_parser:owl_parse(../owl/comp_spatial.owl,false,false,true)
%   library(comp_spatial) compiled into comp_spatial 0.01 sec, 25,256 bytes
Warning: /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/comp_spatial/prolog/init.pl:32:
    Goal (directive) failed: user:owl_parser:owl_parse(/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/comp_spatial/owl/comp_spatial.owl,false,false,true)
%  /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/comp_spatial/prolog/init.pl compiled 0.04 sec, 69,248 bytes
%   library(semweb/actionmodel) compiled into actionmodel 0.01 sec, 63,772 bytes
% Parsed "ccrl2_semantic_map.owl" in 0.07 sec; 2,976 triples
Warning: /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/ias_semantic_map/prolog/ccrl2_semantic_map.pl:27:
    Goal (directive) failed: user:owl_parser:owl_parse(/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/ias_semantic_map/owl/ccrl2_semantic_map.owl,false,false,true)
%  ccrl2_semantic_map compiled 0.08 sec, 111,808 bytes
%  semantic_map_utils compiled into ias_semantic_map 0.00 sec, 8,520 bytes
% /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/knowrob/ias_semantic_map/prolog/init.pl compiled 0.12 sec, 202,448 bytes
true.

?- probability_given(knowrob:'OmicsLocations', Obj, knowrob:'Kitchen', Pr).
Obj = 'http://ias.cs.tum.edu/kb/knowrob.owl#CitrusFruit',
Pr = 0.003865979381443299 ;
Obj = 'http://ias.cs.tum.edu/kb/knowrob.owl#Bowl-Eating',
Pr = 0.006443298969072165 ;
Obj = 'http://ias.cs.tum.edu/kb/knowrob.owl#PhysicalDevice',
Pr = 0.037371134020618556 .

?- visualisation_canvas(C).
ControlP5 0.5.4 infos, comments, questions at http://www.sojamo.de/libraries/controlP5
PeasyCam v105
lights() is not available with this renderer.
Nov 24, 2012 5:51:33 PM controlP5.ControlWindow init
INFO: You are using renderer processing.core.PGraphics3D.
In order to render controlP5 elements you need to call the ControlP5's draw() manually.
Suggestion is to put controlP5.draw(); at the bottom of the draw function of your sketch.
C = @'J#00000000000160392660'.

?- probability_given(knowrob:'OmicsLocations', Obj, knowrob:'Kitchen', Pr), add_object(Obj, Pr, $C).
ERROR: Undefined procedure: add_object/3
ERROR:     However, there are definitions for:
ERROR:         mod_vis:add_object/2
false.

?- probability_given(knowrob:'OmicsLocations', Obj, knowrob:'Kitchen', Pr), display_informations_for(Obj, Pr, $C).
ERROR: Undefined procedure: display_informations_for/3
ERROR:     However, there are definitions for:
ERROR:         mod_vis:display_information_for/2
false.

?-
```

---

((1))Is there help to learn how to makeup this query ?!

```
?- probability_given(knowrob:'OmicsLocations', Obj, knowrob:'Kitchen', Pr).
```

((2)) How to visualize the knowrob_omics ?!

((3)) How to start doing commonsense about my own environment and objects ?!

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48976/visualize-omics-?!/) by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2012-11-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2012-11-23**:
What would you like to visualize? You get object classes back, if you would like to visualize object positions, you need to find the corresponding instances.

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2012-11-24**:
@moritz see update please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are several issues:

1. The inference returns object classes ("citrus fruits can usually be found in kitchens"), the visualization needs concrete object instances that have a position ("THAT lemon in THIS kitchen"). You can't visualize "a citrus fruit".
2. ERROR: Undefined procedure: add_object/3
   ERROR:     However, there are definitions for:
   ERROR:         mod_vis:add_object/2

means that there is no predicate add_object that accepts three arguments, only one that accepts two. Like most other programming languages, Prolog doesn't allow you to just add arguments to a predicate call (what is it supposed do with them?)

3. ERROR: Undefined procedure: display_informations_for/3
   ERROR:     However, there are definitions for:
   ERROR:         mod_vis:display_information_for/2

is an obvious typo. Please do at least read the error messages before asking.

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2012-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1